# Generate objects in django template dynamically

Tags: python, django, templates, for-loop

I have 2 models in my system:

```
class Display(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
    UE = models.CharField
    description

class Register(models.Model):
    temp1 = models.FloatField()
    temp2 = models.FloatField()
    flow = models.FloatField()
```

I create displays using for inside a template, but the value of each display is a respective field in Register model. I can't make the loop with Register because i use only row (i can't loop fields). Understand?

Take a look of my code:

View:

```
def main(request):
dp_col = Display.objects.all()
reg = Registers.objects.latest('pk')
context = {
    'dp_col': dp_col,
    'reg':reg
}
return render(request,'operation.html',context)
```

Template:

```
{% for dp in dp_col %}
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <div class="display-content">
                <div class="display-data">
                    <h3 class="text-center display-desc">{{dp.name}}
                         <span>:</span> 
                         <span class="text-center display-value">I need put the value of each field here</span>
                         <span class='display-unit'>  {{dp.UE}}</span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <!--colocar alguma coisa aqui, caso não tenha nada no for-->
    {% endfor %}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily solved by using a Django Forms:

yourapp/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class DisplayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Display
        fields = '__all__'
```

yourapp/views.py

```
from .forms import DisplayForm

def main(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = DisplayForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = DisplayForm()

    return render(request, 'operation.html', {'form': form})
```

In operations.html:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Or if you want custom html in each field:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% for field in form %}
       {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Comment: I need this in a first call to my view. It's a GET method. I make this to avoid to repeat code of the display in template.

Comment: Take a look in my template in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16BpN.png
The tittle and UE data come from Display model, and the value of field come from Register Model. Before call view i make  a query which returns the last register from Register table. But i can't iterate these queryset because have 1 register.